# TOC spacing problem

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir

[image]I have a problem with spacing in my TOC. Parts and chapters are well spaced right now, but the unnumbered sections are not. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,book,12pt]{memoir}

% Marges
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

% Vormgeving
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}



\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}

% Delen
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty} % change the part pagestyle
\renewcommand{\partpageend}{} %% can write after part title
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       { \centering

        \par\vspace{8pt}}
}

% Hoofdstukken
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
%\large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
\Large\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
%\par\nobreak
%\vskip 20\p@
\fi
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 12\p@
}}
\makeatother

% Secties
\makeatletter
\def\@makesectionhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
%\large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
\normalsize \bfseries \thesection.\space%
%\par\nobreak
%\vskip 20\p@
\fi
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\normalsize \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 12\p@
}}
\makeatother

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}


\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}
\setsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont}

\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}

\setlength\beforechapskip{-1\baselineskip}
\setlength\afterchapskip{1\baselineskip}

\setlength\beforesecskip{-1\baselineskip}
\setlength\aftersecskip{1\baselineskip}

% Kop- en voettekst
\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{ruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}

\makeevenfoot{headings}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\rightmark}

\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{ruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}

\makeevenhead{headings}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeevenhead{ruled}{\leftmark}{}{}
\pagestyle{ruled}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{chapter}{}{}{}

\makefootrule{chapter}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{\footruleskip}

\renewcommand\chaptermarksn[1]{}
\renewcommand\sectionmarksn[1]{}


% inhoudsopgave

\setlength\cftpartnumwidth{2em}
\let\oldparttitlefont\parttitlefont
\def\cftpartaftersnum{.} 

\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{2em}
\let\oldchaptitlefont\chaptitlefont
\def\contentstitlefont{\bfseries\Large}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\def\cftchapteraftersnum{.} 

\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{2em}

\begin{document}

\part{Part name}
\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{section name}
\section{section name}
\section{section name}

\part{Part name}
\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{section name}
\section{section name}
\section{section name}

\newpage

\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\contentstitlefont}
\tableofcontents*
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\oldchaptitlefont}

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that `tocloft` does nothing with `memoir`, which have a similar interface build in. you might want to add an image of what you see at your end as well, that makes it easier to understand your question

Comment: If you run the script and have a look at the ToC, you might see what I am trying to arrange.

Comment: Yes, and if you add an image then people not at a PC can also see what is going on and give their answer if they already know the solution. And after running your example, I don't see the problem. You might want to revise the question to provide more details.

Comment: Also note that most of the code in the example can be removed as it is not related to how the TOC looks.

Comment: There is an image right now.

Comment: I see the problem and thank you for removing that last comment, that was rather rude. The image explains the problem your text does not. I cook up a solution. It is not that hard.

Comment: That might be the result of talking about - for me - complicated issues in a foreign language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you're after? (I removed irrelevant code from the example). BTW: I don't understand the purpose of the redefinition of `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makesectionhead`, use the build in interface instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{memoir}

% number until chapters
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}

% add dots
\renewcommand\cftpartaftersnum{.} 
\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnum{.} 

% next we want the part, chapter and section title to have the same
% starting line

% set size of the box with the number
\setlength\cftpartnumwidth{3em}
\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{\cftpartnumwidth}
% set the indent of the sections (as they are un-numbered)
\setlength\cftsectionindent{\cftpartnumwidth}

\newcommand\test{
  \part{Part name}
  \chapter{Chapter name}
  \section{section name}
  \section{section name}
  \section{section name}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\test

\test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can of course adjust the comment "indent" see the comments in the code.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you so much.

I am not a  very experienced user of Latex and I am learning by copying, trying and trying again. 

But again, thank you very much.

Comment: The book is getting beautiful right now, including gregorian notation.